# Doom 3 source: why does a class representing 2-vectors overload the subscript operator twice?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I thought I'd try beefing up my C++ and OpenGL by looking at the recently-released Doom 3 source. Much learned so far, but I've hit a wall. The class detailed [here](https://dev.visucore.com/doom3/doxygen/classid_vec2.html) has methods

```
float  operator[] (int index) const
```

and

```
float &  operator[] (int index)
```

whose bodies both read

```
return ( &x )[ index ];
```

where `x` is one of the class' two data members (the other being `y`; this class is for 2-vectors).

While I can understand the syntax of each version's header/prototype, I don't get why they're both present.

`const` seems to appear (or not appear, as preferred) only to distinguish the headers sufficiently to allow compilation. (That is, remove `const` and VS2010 refuses to compile, similarly if both headers end in `const`.)

And why return a ref to a float? None of the class' seven other float-type methods do this, so I'm guessing efficiency isn't a factor (tho' maybe this operator's called vastly more often than the others).

Appreciate any insight as to what's going on here...

Comment: I'm sure you'll get better answers, but quickly: The first method is `const` to allow you to access the members for a vector that's `const` (i.e. read but not write). The other method allows you to modify the members for a vector that's not `const` (i.e. the reference allows you to read and write).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common idiom (known as "const overloading").  See the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12.

The ambiguity is resolved by whether `*this` is `const` or not.  On a `const` object, the `const` overload is called, in which case it acts in a read-only style.  On a non-`const` object, the non-`const` is called, in which case it acts in a read/write style.

Note, crucially, that this is **not** a way of distinguishing between read and write accesses.

Comment: I have the sudden urge to standard-quote this answer into hell, but alas, it's the only sensible way to explain it to non-standardese speakers. :) Also, what @Kerrek said. Cv-qualification on `this` would be `X* cv`, while it's `cv X*` (see §9.3.2/1).

Comment: For the interested, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8610728/500104) goes into some of the details on how overload resolution works. It's a fairly complicated process, so prepare yourself. :) It also explains some stuff about `*this`, and why the overload resolution isn't based on that (hint: `this` only exists inside a non-static member function).

Comment: Thanks Oli, Xeo. Now, who on earth is this KerrekSB?!

Answer (score 1):

Think of them as a related pair of *getter* and *setter* methods for subscripted elements. The `float & operator[](int index)` is the *setter* version and allows you to use syntax like so:

```
theObject[anIndex] = 1.0;
```

This requires that `theObject` is available to you as a non-`const` object (or through an `Object *` or `Object &`).

Answer (score 0):

In the case without const, you are using a reference because you want to change the value when calling the function. Eg setting a value: a[11] = 5.0;

The case with const is added because other functions can only be declared as const functions if all other functions that they call are also const functions.

Answer (score 0):

> And why return a ref to a float?

The reason to return a reference to a float is to allow the caller to modify that float. (By the way, efficiency *wouldn't* be a reason for this, since pointers tend to be at least as big as floats, so the extra indirection is pure cost.)

`const` at the end of a method signature indicates that it can safely be called on a `const` object/reference/expression. So, if `v` is an `idVec2`, then `v[0]` may be used as an lvalue (and `v[0] = 3.0f` will actually set `v[0]`), but if `v` is a `const idVec2`, then `v[0]` can only be used as an rvalue (meaning that `v[0] = 3.0f` is ilegal).