# operator[](const char *) ambiguity

Tags: c++

The following code

```
#include <string>

struct Foo {
    operator double() {
        return 1;
    }

    int operator[](std::string x) {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo()["abcd"];
}
```

Compiles fine with g++ but fails with clang and intel compilers because of an ambiguity between the declared method and native operator `[]`.

It would be clear for me if `Foo` had an implicit conversion to `int`, but here the conversion is to `double`. Doesn't that solve the ambiguity?

Comment: What happens if you remove the conversion operator to `double`?

Comment: Works fine on clang without the conversion operator for me.

Comment: This is pretty much the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914986/should-this-compile-overload-resolution-and-implicit-conversions

Comment: Does it compile with icc when you remove `Foo::operator[]`?

Comment: @n.m. Checked with icl (the Windows version of icc) on my computer, and it does compile. But then icl also wrongly compiles one of the examples in §13.3.1.2 [over.match.oper]/p7 that the standard says shouldn't compile, so...

Comment: @T.C. so clang and icc have essentially the same bug and gcc has a different bug.

Comment: @n.m. Pretty much. The example in that paragraph has two separate errors. Clang accepts both, icc accepts one, gcc accepts neither but messes up operator overload resolution in a different way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

§13.3.3.1.2 [over.ics.user]/p1-2:

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard
>   conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion (12.3)
>   followed by a second standard conversion sequence. If the user-defined
>   conversion is specified by a constructor (12.3.1), the initial
>   standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the type
>   required by the argument of the constructor. If the user-defined
>   conversion is specified by a conversion function (12.3.2), the initial
>   standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit
>   object parameter of the conversion function.
>
> The second standard conversion sequence converts the result of the
>   user-defined conversion to the target type for the sequence.

In particular, there's an implicit conversion from floating point to integral type (§4.9 [conv.fpint]/p1):

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
>   is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
>   be represented in the destination type.

For overload resolution purposes, the applicable candidates are:

```
Foo::operator[](std::string x)              // overload
operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, const char *);   // built-in
```

Given an argument list of types `(Foo, const char [5])`.

To match the first operator function, the first argument is an exact match; the second requires a user-defined conversion.

To match the second built-in function, the first argument requires a user-defined conversion sequence (the user-defined conversion to `double` followed by a standard conversion to `std::ptrdiff_t`, a floating-integral conversion). The second argument requires a standard array-to-pointer conversion (still exact match rank), which is better than a user-defined conversion.

Thus for the first argument the first function is better; for the second argument the second function is better, we have a criss-cross situation, overload resolution fails, and the program is ill-formed.

Note that, while for the purposes of operator overload resolution, a user-defined conversion sequence can have two standard conversion sequences (one before and one after the user-defined conversion), and operands of non-class-type can be converted to match the candidates, if a built-in operator is selected, the second standard conversion sequence is not applied for operands of class type, and no conversion at all is applied for operands for non-class type before the operator is interpreted as a built-in (§13.3.1.2 [over.match.oper]/p7):

> If a built-in candidate is selected by overload resolution, the
>   operands of class type are converted to the types of the corresponding
>   parameters of the selected operation function, except that the second
>   standard conversion sequence of a user-defined conversion sequence
>   (13.3.3.1.2) is not applied. Then the operator is treated as the
>   corresponding built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.

Thus if `Foo::operator[](std::string x)` is removed, the compiler should report an error, though clang doesn't. This is an obvious clang bug, as [it fails to reject the example given in the standard](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25bcc0549a19921f).

Comment: Yet clang rejects `1.0["foo"]` as invalid.

Comment: @n.m. That's correct as well - there's no overload resolution in that case. Moreover, if overload resolution selects a built-in, the result's not necessarily valid.

Comment: On my machine clang complains about ambiguity between `Foo::operator[](std::string)` and the *built-in* `operator[](int, const char *)` (no ptrdiff_t involved). When you remove `Foo::operator[]` it happily selects a built-in with no error. But the built-in requires one of the arguments to be of integral type. How do you explain this?

Comment: @n.m. `std::ptrdiff_t` is a typedef to a signed integer type (apparently on your machine it's `int` - I assume it's 32-bit?). The second is a clang bug. It shouldn't convert arguments of non-class type or apply the second standard conversion sequence for arguments of class type, but it does.

Comment: There are two possible explanations. (1) The built-in is not viable, therefore it should be dropped from the overload set, and `Foo::operator[]` selected as the only remaining element. Since clang erroneously thinks the built-in is viable, this doesn't happen. (2) The standard implies the built-in is viable, and requires it to be rejected *after* the overload resolution stage. If this is the case, it's a defect in the standard (an unexpected and illogical behaviour, not warranted by anything).

Comment: @n.m. The built-in is definitely viable for overload resolution purposes, since there's an implicit conversion sequence from `Foo` to `int` or `long` (via `double`). Only after it's selected, will it be rejected in the next step.

Comment: Hm, it looks like 13.6/1 says this is by design, rather than by mistake.