# Use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous with template cast operator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code compiles well in gcc 7.3.0, but doesn't compiles with clang 6.0.0.

```
#include <string>

struct X {
    X() : x(10) {}
    int operator[](std::string str) { return x + str[0]; }
    template <typename T> operator T() { return x; } // (1) fails only in clang
    //operator int() { return x; } // (2) fails both in gcc and clang
private:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    X x;
    int y = 20;
    int z = int(x);
    return x["abc"];
}
```

I used command `clang++ 1.cpp -std=c++98` with specifying different standard versions. I tried c++98,11,14,17,2a. In all cases an error is the same. Error message in clang is following:

```
1.cpp:14:13: error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'X' and 'const char [4]')
    return x["abc"];
           ~^~~~~~
1.cpp:5:9: note: candidate function
    int operator[](std::string str) { return x + str[0]; }
        ^
1.cpp:14:13: note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const char *)
    return x["abc"];
            ^
1.cpp:14:13: note: built-in candidate operator[](long, const volatile char *)
1 error generated.
```

What compiler correctly follows the standard in this situation? Is it a valid code?

The description of the problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8917084), but it is about situation (2). I am interested in case (1).

Comment: `built-in operator[](long, const char *)` ... that's... what is going on...?

Comment: To my knowledge there should be no ambiguity. What compiler do you use?

Comment: What version of C++ please

Comment: @bolov https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.built#14 `T&      operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, T*);`, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GCC is wrong. The template case shouldn't make any difference.

[[over.match.best]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.best#1) says:

> Define ICSi(F) as follows:
>
> - ...
> - let ICSi(F) denote the implicit conversion sequence that converts the i-th argument in the list to the type of the i-th parameter of viable function F. [over.best.ics] defines the implicit conversion sequences and [over.ics.rank] defines what it means for one implicit conversion sequence to be a better conversion sequence or worse conversion sequence than another.
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), **and** ...

The two viable candidates are

```
int         operator[](X&,             std::string); // F1
const char& operator[](std::ptrdiff_t, const char*); // F2
```

... and ICS1(F1) (`X -> X&`) is better than ICS1(F2) (`X -> std::ptrdiff_t`), no matter whether or not `X -> std::ptrdiff_t` is through a template conversion function, but ICS2(F1) (`const char[4] -> std::string`) is worse than ICS2(F2) (`const char[4] -> const char*`). So neither function is better than the other, resulting in ambiguity.

This has been reported as a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85250).

Comment: To be explicit (to help anyone else who might not get it immediately, like I didn't): There is an ambiguity, so the code should not compile. GCC doesn't recognize the template conversion function as a part of the valid conversion path for calling F2, so it doesn't see any ambiguity and compiles. This misrecognition is described in the linked GCC bug.

Comment: The lesson of this as that you should not have a cast operator to any integral type for which you've also defined `operator []`. This is one of the C anachronisms that should be abandon IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that there is one conversion on each path:

- first from `"abc"` to `std::string` and then `operator[]` call.
- second from `x` to `std::ptrdiff_t` and then the `operator[]` for an `std::ptrdiff_t` and a `const char*`.

So the solution is to make the conversion operator `explicit`:

```
int operator[](const std::string& str) { return x + str[0]; }
template <typename T>
explicit operator T() { return x; } // (1) fails only in clang
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fair enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, not following your comment.

Comment: I mean that I'm no longer 100% sure because I missed that `x` is an `X` not a `long`. So another user-defined conversion is in play here

Comment: Yes, hence the `explicit` solution to make is work without adding extra literals.

Comment: Of course the explicit conversion has its own issues, but maybe better in the long run anyway.

Comment: Isn't conversion from `X` to `int` weaker than `const char*` to `std::string` because we use template here, not an exact function like in case (2)? Do you mean that all compilers should fail in situation (1)?

Comment: I think that's one of the points @LightnessRacesinOrbit made in a comment. I don't know which one is correct (gcc or clang), maybe be worth opening a bug report with clang.

Comment: Meh, nah. I almost had it. But I'd have had to delve really deep into candidate matching. Time's up! Hopefully someone else can finish it :P

Comment: @BhavinChirag templates lose to non-templates during overload resolution, but I have found no template-based ranking of user-defined conversion sequences in the standard.