# Function returning struct as LValue

Tags: c++, gcc

In the following snippet, why does the line `o.margin() = m;` compile without fault? It easily deserves a warning, since it will almost invariably be a mistake. I would actually have thought it to be an error since it puts an R-Value on the left side of an assignment.

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct Margin
{
    Margin(int val=0) : val(val) {};
    int val;
};

struct Option
{
    Margin m;
    int z=0;

    Margin margin()const { return m; }
    int zoomLevel() { return z; }
};


int main()
{
    Option o;
    std::cout << "Margin is: "<< o.margin().val << std::endl;

    Margin m = { 3 };

    // The following line is a no-op, which generates no warning:
    o.margin() = m;

    // The following line is an error
    // GCC 4.9.0: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    // clang 3.8: error: expression is not assignable
    // MSVC 2015: error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value
     o.zoomLevel() = 2;

    std::cout << "Margin is: "<< o.margin().val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Margin is: 0
Margin is: 0
```

Comment: "Why is it not a warning" Because it's not. What's your actual question?

Comment: @king_nak The language lawyer tag is really not necessary. This is a QOI issue, not a language issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tag or QOI, but I meant it should be "at least a warning". I would have assumed it to be an error actually.

Comment: QOI, I assume, means "quality of implementation." Which is exactly what this is about. Although the standard technically allows it (making [language-lawyer] inapplicable), there are vanishingly few reasons why you would want to write code like this, so a quality implementation arguably should issue a warning about it. Quite like how assignment is allowed in a conditional expression, but 99% of the time, this is not what you meant to do, so compilers now issue warnings when you write `if (foo = 42)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are allowed to modify return types of class type (by calling non const methods on it):

3.10/5 from n4140

> 5 An lvalue for an object is necessary in order to modify the object
>   except that an rvalue of class type can also be used to modify its
>   referent under certain circumstances. [ Example: a member function
>   called for an object (9.3) can modify the object. —end example ]

your code:

```
o.margin() = m;
```

is actually the same as

```
o.margin().operator=( Margin(m) );
```

so non const method is called, if you change it to:

```
o.margin().val = m;
```

then you will get an error.

on the other hand here:

o.zoomLevel() = 2;

`zoomLevel()` returns non-class type, so you cannot modify it.

Comment: I am accepting this an an answer since it references the standard. I am still surprised, though, that no major compiler issues a warning.

Comment: @bgp2000 no warning is because standard allows it and there are idioms which uses this feature, for example: named-parameter-idiom : https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom

Comment: I never doubted that one can call a member function on an rvalue. I just had never thought it would work with the assignment operator. Do you know of an idiom using the assignment operator?

Comment: No, but its also a function

Answer (score 10):

When `o` is an object of class type, `operator=` is a member function. The code    `o.margin() = m;` is equivalent to `o.margin().operator=(m);`.

You are allowed to call members functions of temporary class objects, similar to how you access a member in `o.margin().val`.

Also, the class' assignment operator can be overridden and not be a no-op at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to forbid such uses, since C++11 you can use a [reference qualifier](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1821.htm) on the assignment operator:

```
Margin& operator=(const Margin&) & = default;
```

This will generate the following error on GCC 5.1:

```
error: passing 'Margin' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

You might also want to check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306226/what-does-an-ampersand-after-this-assignment-operator-mean?lq=1).

Comment: That is interesting. The new c++ credo seems to be: If in doubt, add an ampersand. I am afraid that 99.9% of all c++ users won't know the meaning of that line. A -Warn-on-rvalue-assignment flag would be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

`Option::margin()` is a const-*accessible* member function that returns a mutable `Margin` object.

Consequently, assigning the temporary is valid because using `operator=` on `Margin` is valid. In this case it has no side-effects and basically does nothing. A particular implementation of a C++ compiler *may* choose to implement semantic analysis and warn you, but it's completely outside the scope of the language.