# Why parameters of universal reference needs to be casted, before used?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

In the [lecture about universal references](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11), Scott Meyers (at approximately 40th minute) said that objects that are universal references should be converted into real type, before used. In other words, whenever there is a template function with universal reference type, `std::forward` should be used before operators and expressions are used, otherwise a copy of the object might be made.

My understanding of this is in the following example :

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A() { std::cout<<"constr"<<std::endl; }
  A(const A&) { std::cout<<"copy constr"<<std::endl; }
  A(A&&) { std::cout<<"move constr"<<std::endl; }
  A& operator=(const A&) { std::cout<<"copy assign"<<std::endl; return *this; }
  A& operator=(A&&) { std::cout<<"move assign"<<std::endl; return *this; }

  ~A() { std::cout<<"destr"<<std::endl; }

  void bar()
  {
    std::cout<<"bar"<<std::endl;
  }
};

A getA()
{
  A a;
  return a;
}

template< typename T >
void callBar( T && a )
{
  std::forward< T >( a ).bar();
}

int main()
{
  {
    std::cout<<"\n1"<<std::endl;
    A a;
    callBar( a );
  }

  {
    std::cout<<"\n2"<<std::endl;
    callBar( getA() );
  }
}
```

As expected, the output is :

```
1
constr
bar
destr

2
constr
move constr
destr
bar
destr
```

The question really is why is this needed?

```
std::forward< T >( a ).bar();
```

I tried without std::forward, and it seems to work fine (the output is the same).

Similarly, why he recommends to use move inside the function with rvalue? (the answer is the same as for std::forward)

```
void callBar( A && a )
{
  std::move(a).bar();
}
```

I understand that both `std::move` and `std::forward` are just casts to appropriate types, but are these casts really needed in the above example?

Bonus : how can the example be modified to produce the copy of the object that is passed to that function?

Comment: You beat me by not much asking the same question. I'm also looking for explanation on this.

Comment: @Vikas So, does it mean that my understanding was correct? You do need to use move in functions using rvalue?

Comment: What I meant that I also have similar doubts after watching his talk. And I was also going to ask this question here :-).

Comment: [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8610571/500104) :)

Comment: What's the point in moving in callBar you're not going to take a copy?

Comment: @KazDragon Take a look into my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12854624/476681). `std::move` is just a cast. If you do not do it, you are going to use the parameter `a`, which is a lvalue reference. `std::move` turns it into rvalue reference. In my answer you can see a modifications to the original example, which explains what is going on. With these modifications, it should be clear

Comment: @BЈовић Socratic method.  Move is an optimisation for a copy.  I was suggesting that the reason might become clear if there were actually copies at the end of the call chain.

Comment: @KazDragon `void callBar( A && a )
{ A ca( a );
  ca.bar();
}` Like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is said in the lecture is this :

```
void doWork( Widget&& param )
{
  ops and exprs using std::move(param)
}
```

> SM: What this means is : if you see code that takes a rvalue reference, and you see use of that parameter without being wrapped by move, it is highly suspect.

After some thought, I realized that it is correct (as expected). Changing the `callBar` function in the original example to this demonstrate the point :

```
void reallyCallBar( A& la )
{
  std::cout<<"lvalue"<<std::endl;
  la.bar();
}

void reallyCallBar( A&& ra )
{
  std::cout<<"rvalue"<<std::endl;
  ra.bar();
}

template< typename T >
void callBar( T && a )
{
  reallyCallBar( std::forward< T >( a ) );
}
```

If the `std::forward` wasn't used in `callBar`, then the `reallyCallBar( A& )` would be used. Because `a` in `callBar` is a lvalue reference. `std::forward` makes it a rvalue, when the universal reference is the rvalue reference.

Next modification proves the point even further :

```
void reallyCallBar( A& la )
{
  std::cout<<"lvalue"<<std::endl;
  la.bar();
}

void reallyCallBar( A&& ra )
{
  std::cout<<"rvalue"<<std::endl;
  reallyCallBar( ra );
}

template< typename T >
void callBar( T && a )
{
  reallyCallBar( std::forward< T >( a ) );
}
```

Since `std::move` is not used in the `reallyCallBar( A&& ra )` function, it doesn't enter the endless loop. Instead it calls the version taking lvalue reference.

Therefore (as explained in the lecture) :

- `std::forward` must be used on universal references
- `std::move` must be used on rvalue references

Answer (score 2):

It's needed because `bar()` might be overloaded separately for rvalues and lvalues. That means that it might do something differently, or flat out not be allowed, depending on if you correctly described `a` as an lvalue or an rvalue, or just blindly treated it like an lvalue. Right now, most users don't use this functionality and don't have exposure to it because the most popular compilers don't support it - even GCC 4.8 doesn't support rvalue `*this`. But it is Standard.

Comment: So, in that case, this should be ok as well : `void callBar( A && a )
{
  std::move(a).bar();std::move(a).bar();
}`, and as explained in the video, the parameter should be casted before being accessed. Right?

Comment: Depends. Are you ok with `bar()` potentially stealing `a`'s resources? Because it might be implemented that way

Answer (score 2):

There are two different uses for `&&` on a parameter to a function. For an ordinary function it means that the argument is an rvalue reference; for a template function it means that it can be **either** an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference:

```
template <class T> void f(T&&); // rvalue or lvalue
void g(T&&);                    // rvalue only
void g(T&)                      // lvalue only

void h() {
    C c;
    f(c);            // okay: calls f(T&)
    f(std::move(c)); // okay: calls f(T&&)
    g(c);            // error: c is not an rvalue
    g(std::move(c)); // okay: move turns c into an rvalue
}
```

Inside `f` and `g`, applying `std::forward` to such an argument preserves the lvalue- or rvalue-ness of the argument, so in general that's the safest way to forward an argument to another function.

Comment: `f(c);            // error: c is not an rvalue
` Why this fails? Shouldn't it accept it, since T&& is the universal reference (as explained in the lecture)?

Comment: @BЈовић - no, outside of a template, `&&` means rvalue reference. It's only in a template that it means rvalue reference or lvalue reference.

Comment: @PeteBecker but f() *is* a template, so `f(c)` is correct. Also, I'd change the signature of `g` to `g(C&&)` and `g(C&)` to make the code and comments match. (in the present form `g(c)` is an error)

Comment: @mitchnull - whoops, I got the comments backwards. I'll fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
void callBar( A && a )
{
  std::move(a).bar();
}
```

In the case where you have an rvalue reference as a parameter, which can **only bind to an rvalue** you normally want to use move semantics to move from this this rvalue and take it's guts out.

The parameter itself is an *lvalue*, because it is a named thing.  You can take it's address.

So in order to make it an rvalue again and be able to move from it, you apply `std::move` to it.  If you were literally just calling a function on a passed parameter, I don't see why you'd have a parameter that is an rvalue reference.

You only want to pass an rvalue reference if you are going to move from this inside your function, which is why you then have to use `std::move`.

Your example here doesn't actually make much sense in that respect.

Comment: The decision to move should be made at the call site. A function should not decide to move an argument that it got by reference: it can't know that moving is safe.

Comment: @PeteBecker What's the point of rvalue references in parameter lists if not for passing arguments that are safe to move from?

Comment: @LucDanton - `&&` on an argument whose type is a template parameter doesn't tell you that it's an rvalue; that's the point of the "universal reference" term. `template <class T> void f(C&&); void h() { C c; f(c); }` Here, `f` gets called with an lvalue. `void g(C&&); void h() { C c; f(c); }` Here, the call to `f` is an error, because `c` is an lvalue and `g` expects an rvalue.

Comment: Ah seemed I missed the fact that `callBar` is indeed an induced context and therefore an universial reference. Hmmmm

Comment: @PeteBecker While I haven't seen the talk, I've taken the second `callBar` (in the OP) to not be a template. 'Similarly' introducing a parallel between universal reference+`std::forward` and rvalue reference+`std::move`.

Comment: @LucDanton - could be, although it **really** should have a different name if it's purpose is to show something different.

Comment: @PeteBecker So, what you are saying is that the move should not be called in a function taking a rvalue reference? (forward for universal reference)

Comment: @BЈовић - no, it's okay if it's an rvalue reference, and that's what you have in a normal function that takes its argument as a `&&`. In a **template** a parameter that comes in as a `&&` can be either an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference, and in that case, the code shouldn't call `move`.

Comment: @PeteBecker The comment above could have been an answer :P