# std::vector move semantics in a data structure

Tags: c++, c++11

For this simple circular queue, I want to support C++11's move semantics so the push() doesnt incur a memory copy if it doesnt need to.

```
Circular<struct r, 1024> queue_;
queue_.push( { r0, r1 } );
```

However I'm concerned my implementation, specifically the second push() below, is unnecessary or too wordy.

```
template<typename T, size_t capacity>
class Circular
{
public:
  Circular()
    : have_(capacity)
    , w_(0)
    , r_(0)
  {}
  ~Circular() {}
  void push( const T& x ) { have_[ w_++ % capacity ] = x; }
  void push( T&& x )    { have_[ w_++ % capacity ] = x; }
...
protected:
  std::vector<T> have_;
  size_t w_;
  size_t r_;
};
```

Is there a better way to get these semantics? (Edit: are the intended semantics in fact implemented?)

**Followup**: Can we avoid repeating the body of the push() method while preserving the intended behavior?

Comment: Your code does nothing. You need `have_[foo] = std::move(x);` (E.g. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13219621/596781).)

Comment: To clarify what Kerrek means by "your code does nothing": without an explicit `std::move()` around `x` in `void push(T&& x)`, the assignment will still call the copy assignment operator even when `T` has a move assignment operator. Even though that function takes an rvalue reference, its parameter `x` is an lvalue because it has a name (the name `x`).

Comment: Is there a way not to repeat the body of the push() twice. I.e. can I call one from the other while maintaining the desired behaviors?

Comment: Just note: performance of this buffer will be significantly different if `capacity` is power of 2 or not. You may want to specify capacity as exponent of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a better way to get these semantics: in fact, there is a way to *actually* get these semantics where your code currently does not. :-)

Accepting an rvalue reference into `push` is one half of the equation, but within that function it's an lvalue expression again so you need to add `std::move` to "pass the rvalue reference along".

```
void push( T&& x )    { have_[ w_++ % capacity ] = std::move(x); }
```

Beyond that, I can't think of any particular improvements to make.

Comment: Not a forwarding (universal) reference. The template parameter is on the class, so the T is already fixed when the `push` member function is called. Forwarding references would require template argument deduction on the `T` to kick in.