# move vs forward on universal references

Tags: c++, move, forward

I was trying out a program on universal references by applying `std::move` and `std::forward` on them. Until today I assumed that both were the same but in this very program (given below) the output amazed me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class X
{
    string take="";
    public:
    template<class T>
    void pass1 (T &&str)   // str is a universal reference as it can bind to anything, both rvalue and lvalue references
    {
        take=move(str);
    }
    template<class T>
    void pass2 (T &&str)
    {
        take=forward<T>(str);
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<"take = "<<take<<"\n";
    }
}obj;

int main()
{
    cout<<"using move on universal reference:-\n";
    string str="he is there";
    cout<<"str = "<<str<<'\n';
    obj.pass1(str);
    obj.show();
    if (str.empty())
    cout<<"str is empty\n\n";
    else
    cout<<"str isnt empty\n\n";
    cout<<"using forward on universal reference:-\n";
    str="he was there";
    cout<<"str = "<<str<<'\n';
    obj.pass2(str);
    obj.show();
    if (str.empty())
    cout<<"str is empty\n\n";
    else
    cout<<"str isnt empty\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
using move on universal reference:-
str = he is there
take = he is there
str is empty

using forward on universal reference:-
str = he was there
take = he was there
str isnt empty
*/
```

My questions are:

1. Why are the outputs different?
2. Don't `move` and `forward` work similarly? How are they working differently (in context with the above code)?

Comment: Use `move` with rvalue references and `forward<T>` with forwarding ("universal") references.

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9671749, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal references mean that they can bind with apparently anything, both rvalues and lvalues. `move` & `forward` donot MOVE ANYTHING LITERALLY and rather perform casts ie they cast the argument to an `rvalue`. The difference is that `move` casts unconditionally whereas `forward` will cast conditionally: it casts to an rvalue only if its argument was initialized with an rvalue. So `move` always casts whereas `forward` casts sometimes.
Hence the `forward` in the above case doesn't empty the string as an `lvalue (ie str)` was passed so it  FORWARDED  `str` as an lvalue.

Comment: Thanx for a simpler answer !

Comment: Check Scott Meyer's " Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14" for better explanations. Good luck !

Answer (score 3):

They are different, of course. If they were the same, you would only need one.

`move` constructs rvalue from provided rvalue or lvalue. `forward` deciphers the actual type of the provided argument.

Answer (score 3):

`T &&` has been renamed to a forwarding reference.

In your first example you explicitly call [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) so `str` becomes an r-value reference and it's contents are moved from main to the member in `X`.

In the second example you use [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).  calling `std::forward` on `T` when `T` is an r-value reference will forward the r-value reference to `operator=` and `operator=(std::String&&)` will be called.  If `T` is an l-value then a l-value reference is passed.  Since we have an l-value the `operator=(const std::string&)` will be called and we copy `str` instead of move from it.

Answer (score 3):

Understand two thing:

1) 'move' does not guarantee to move

2) 'forward' does not forward a code.

move is an unconditional operator

forward is a conditional operator.

Confused??

please watch this video: 
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BezbcQIuCsY