# What are the scenarios where assignment from std::forward is preferable over assignment from std::move ? why?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

While learning about `std::exchange` on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) , I came across its "possible implementation" which is pasted below.

```
  template<class T, class U = T>
  T exchange(T& obj, U&& new_value)
  {
      T old_value = std::move(obj);
      obj = std::forward<U>(new_value);
      return old_value;
  }
```

It looked a bit odd to see `obj = std::forward` in an assignment statement instead instead of `std::move`, which I think would have the same effect.

My understanding is that `std::move` is equivalent to a `static_cast` to rvalue reference type (but more expressive) and returns an xvalue always, whereas `std::forward` returns the same value type it is passed.

My question is why is `std:forward` used in above snippet? and is there an easy  rule of thumb to decide when this is the better choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that there's assignment is irrelevant. What distinguishes forward from move is what kind of *argument* they take when used inside your function:

- The argument of `forward` is a forwarding reference parameter of your function.
- The argument of `move` is an rvalue reference parameter of your function (or more generally, anything you know to have no further aliases).

If you `exchange` with an lvalue, you don't want that to be moved-from!

For example, consider:

```
std::vector<int> a, b;

f(std::exchange(a, b));
```

This effectively calls `f(a)` but also performs `a = b;`. It does *not* perform `a = std::move(b)`; `b` is still usable in its original form afterwards!

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219621) of mine, as well as many other related answers like [What is std::move(), and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470), [What's the difference between std::move and std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671749), and links therein.

Comment: typo: move takes an lvalue reference. it casts *to* an rvalue reference.

Comment: Thanks for answer and the links. So the main thing is we do not want to forcibly turn an lvalue reference to an rvalue inside the function and potentially have it invalidated. The code I was looking at the time was just passing { }  as the second argument, but as you say the difference is when b is an lvalue.

Comment: @RichardHodges: No, I meant what I wrote, but I said it poorly. I will adjust it, thanks. (Typical arguments of both forward and move are always lvalues, of course, since they are typically id-expressions.)