# I would like rvalue-based functions to be called on a reference to an rvalue...if there is such a thing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

I have a string class.  Some operators return references, others return values.  Only the ones that return values can take advantage of the rvalue copy constructor or rvalue assignment operator.

I would like the rvalue operator to be called on a reference to an rvalue.

Given these:

```
String(const TCHAR* sz);
String(const String& s);    
String& operator+=(const TCHAR* sz);    
String& operator=(String&& r);
```

And this code:

```
String x;
x = (String("fred") += "foo");
```

It calls the copy constructor, the += operator, but then the COPY CONSTRUCTER again.  I want it to call the rvalue assignment operator!

I added this:

```
String(String&& r)
```

And that makes no difference.

**EDIT:**
I confirmed that if I make my += operator return a value, the rvalue assignment operator will be called.  I have done a lot of performance testing and doing this makes everything a lot slower.

Comment: Gosh darn it, I got two correct answers.  I don't know what to do!

Comment: If you're looking for high-efficiency expression combinations, you probably want to look into expression templates. [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/proto.html) will help you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily differentiate between a "genuine" rvalue and an rvalue reference, but you don't seem to have a motivation to do so. Your overload is fine.

The problem is that rvalue-ness is lost by the `+=` operator. There are three solutions:

1. Manually make it an rvalue: `x = std::move(String("fred") += "foo");`
2. Use non-member overloads. I generally prefer this because it resolves other issues such as applying conversion functions to the left-hand side of a `+=` expression.

   ```
   String& operator+=(String &lhs, const TCHAR* sz);
   String&& operator+=(String &&lhs, const TCHAR* sz);
   ```
3. Use reference qualifiers so that `operator+=` returns an rvalue when applied to an rvalue. Few compilers support this yet.

   ```
   String& operator+=(const TCHAR* sz) &;
   String&& operator+=(const TCHAR* sz) &&;
   ```

Comment: @GManNickG I gotta go, and I've never looked at Boost.Proto so the advantage is yours :P but I will later

Comment: my compiler can't handle it.  I'm using vc2010, maybe the newer vc can do it.

Comment: @johnnycrash #2 should work with any compiler, it's not C++11 or anything. Those declarations either don't go inside `class`, or should be marked `friend` if they are.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the last form.

Comment: … oh, I should mention that to be really non-C++11, you would just erase both `&&`'s from #2. But the resulting declaration would really just be `operator+`, which is effectively the semantics that result in any case. I'll try to remember to edit later and mention Boost.proto.

Comment: Meh, since GMan deleted his answer, I'll just drop my link here, for the explanation what the `&` and `&&` after the functions do: [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8610571/500104) Hope you don't mind. :)