# How to turn method pointer types into function pointer types

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose you have template method that takes a pointer to a method of any type. Inside that template, is there a way to turn the template argument, which is a method pointer type (`void(A::*)()` for example), into a function pointer type with the same return type and parameters, but without the class information (`void(*)()`)?

I looked at the `<type_traits>` header but didn't find anything that would help.

Comment: @Xeo Thanks! I'd mark it as an answer but you only posted a comment :)

Comment: It was incomplete and assumed C++11, but I fleshed it out into an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way in C++11 is partial specialization with a variadic template:

```
template<class PMF> struct pmf_to_pf;

template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct pmf_to_pf<R (C::*)(Args...)>{
  using type = R(*)(Args...); // I like using aliases
};
```

Note that you need a seperate partial specialization for `const` member-functions (and theoretically for [ref-qualified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610571/500104) ones aswell):

```
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
struct pmf_to_pf<R (C::*)(Args...) const>{
  using type = R(*)(Args...);
};
```

With cv-qualifiers (`{nil,const}`, `{nil,volatile}`) and ref-qualifiers (`{nil, &, &&}`), you have a total of `2*2*3 == 12` partial specializations to provide<sup>†</sup>. You normally can leave out the `volatile` qualification ones, dropping the total down to "just" 6. Since most compilers don't support function-ref-qualifiers, you only need 2 really, but be aware of the rest.

---

For C++03 (aka compilers without variadic templates), you can use the following non-variadic form:

```
template<class PMF> struct pmf_to_pf;

template<class Sig, class C>
struct pmf_to_pf<Sig C::*>{
  typedef Sig* type; // 'Sig' is 'R(Args...)' and 'Sig*' is 'R(*)(Args...)'
};
```

Although this doesn't quite work with cv-qualifiers, since I think C++03 didn't allow cv-qualified signatures (e.g. `R(Args...) const`) on which you could partially specialize to remove the `const`.

---

† The `{...}` denote a set of a certain qualifier, with `nil` representing the empty set. Examples:

- `void f() const&` would be `{const}, {nil}, {&}`
- `void f() &&` would be `{nil}, {nil}, {&&}`

And so on.

Comment: I'd expect `using type = R(*)(C*, Args...);` Am I  missing something? Never mind, I reread the OP, it's probably for meta-programming only

Comment: @sehe: Well, that's how I interpreted the question. If OP wanted the `C*` argument, that's an easy fix after all.