# Overload resolution with ref-qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, language-lawyer, ref-qualifier

While working with ref-qualified function overloads, I'm getting different results from *GCC (4.8.1)* and *Clang (2.9 and trunk)*. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
    int& bar() &
    {
        std::cout << "non-const lvalue" << std::endl;
        return _bar;
    }
    //~ int&& bar() &&
    //~ {
    //~     std::cout << "non-const rvalue" << std::endl;
    //~     return std::move(_bar);
    //~ }
    int const& bar() const &
    {
        std::cout << "const lvalue" << std::endl;
        return _bar;
    }
    int const&& bar() const &&
    {
        std::cout << "const rvalue" << std::endl;
        return std::move(_bar);
    }

    int _bar;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo().bar();
}
```

*Clang* compiles it and outputs `"const rvalue"`, while *GCC* thinks this is an ambiguous call with the two const-qualified functions both being best viable candidates. If I provide all 4 overloads, then both compilers output `"non-const rvalue"`.

I would like to know which compiler *--if any--* is doing the right thing, and what are the relevant standard pieces in play.

***Note:*** The reason this actually matters is that the real code declares both const-qualified functions as `constexpr`. Of course, there is no output to `std::cout` and `static_cast` is used instead of `std::move`, so that they are valid `constexpr` definitions. And since in *C++11* `constexpr` still implies `const`, the overload commented out in the sample code cannot be provided as it would redefine the const-qualified rvalue overload.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Firstly, the implicit object parameter is treated as a normal parameter as per 13.3.1.4:

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> — “lvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared without a ref-qualifier or with the & ref-qualifier
>
> — “rvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared with the && ref-qualifier
>
> where X is the class of which the function is a member and cv is the cv-qualification on the member
> function declaration.

So what you are asking is equivalent to the following:

```
void bar(foo&);
void bar(foo&&);
void bar(const foo&);
void bar(const foo&&);

int main()
{
    bar(foo());
}
```

The expression `foo()` is a class prvalue.

Secondly, the non-const lvalue reference version is not viable, as a prvalue cannot bind to it.

This leaves us with three viable functions for overload resolution.

Each has a single implicit object parameter (`const foo&`, `foo&&` or `const foo&&`), so we must rank these three to determine the best match.

In all three case it is a *directly bound* reference binding.  This is described in declarators/initialization (8.5.3).

The ranking of the three possible bindings (`const foo&`, `foo&&` and `const foo&&`) is described in 13.3.3.2.3:

> Standard conversion sequence **S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2** if
>
> - S1 and S2 are reference bindings and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier [this exception doesn't apply here, they all have ref-qualifiers], and **S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue** [a class prvalue is an rvalue] **and S2 binds an lvalue reference**.

This means that both `foo&&` and `const foo&&` are better then `const foo&`.

> - S1 and S2 are reference bindings, and the types to which the references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by **S2 refers is more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers**.

This means that `foo&&` is better than `const foo&&`.

So Clang is right, and it is a bug in GCC.  The overload ranking for `foo().bar()` is as follows:

```
struct foo
{
    int&& bar() &&;             // VIABLE - BEST  (1)
    int const&& bar() const &&; // VIABLE -       (2)
    int const& bar() const &;   // VIABLE - WORST (3)
    int& bar() &;               // NOT VIABLE

    int _bar;
};
```

The bug in GCC seems to apply purely to implicit object parameters (with `ref-qualifiers`), for a normal parameter it seems to get the ranking correct, at least in 4.7.2.

Comment: An rvalue reference is a better match in all cases. This is likely a bug with GGC's ref-qualifiers.

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8610728/500104) might be relevant. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I wish I could upvote it more than once!