# Why is there ambiguity using reference-qualifiers on overloaded methods?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compiles in Clang but not in GCC. When I call `operator()` with an lvalue it works, but not with an rvalue. Why?

```
struct S
{
    bool operator()() const &  { return true; }
    bool operator()() const && { return true; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;

    s();   // works
    S()(); // fails (error: call of '(S) ()' is ambiguous)
}
```

I'm compiling this code on GCC 4.8.

Comment: Okay then, my first thought is GCC not including the ref qualifier in overload resolution. I suppose it's possible, what with 4.8 being the first version that supports them.

Comment: clang happily compiles the code. gcc 4.9.0 20131222 (experimental) also doesn't like the code.

Comment: Try removing the `const` from the rvalue version, or otherwise say `static_cast<const S &&>(S())()`.

Comment: I just found this. It looks completely relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130607/overload-resolution-with-ref-qualifiers. Didn't know that `const` made a difference, so hurray for learning every day.

Comment: @KerrekSB Your first solution works, but not your second (on GCC at least).

Comment: Is the & and && as a non method's parameter is a Clang extension or is defined in the C++11 standard ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 They are defined in the Standard as reference qualifiers (I don't have access to the Standard right now so I can't show you the section in which they are defined).