# rvalue/lvalue const member qualifier, compiles on clang++, fails on g++

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have the following code, in which I overload the member function `test::f` for both `lvalue` and `rvalue` to `*this`

```
#include <iostream>

struct test{
  void f() &{ std::cout << "lvalue"; }
  void f() &&{ std::cout << "rvalue"; }
};

int main(){
  test tst;
  tst.f(); // lvalue, outputs "lvalue"

  // make it a rvalue reference
  std::move(tst).f(); // rvalue, outputs "rvalue"
}
```

Everything works as expected. However, if I add `const`-ness to BOTH `test::f()`, such as

```
      void f() const &{ std::cout << "lvalue"; }
      void f() const &&{ std::cout << "rvalue"; }
```

the code doesn't compile anymore, spitting the error

```
error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
```

What exactly is happening here? Why `f` suddenly becomes ambiguous? Is it because a `rvalue` can bind to a `const` reference also, and the reference collapsing comes into play, i.e. the type becomes && & -> &, i.e. `lvalue`? I don't really understand if this is the reason.

PS: just found out from @T.C. that the code compiles on clang no matter the `const`-ness of `f`. It seems to fail for `const` member functions only on g++ (4.8 / 4.9) (BUT compiles on g++4.10)

PPS: Case closed, question is indeed a dupe, it is indeed a g++ bug, see the link [Overload resolution with ref-qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17130607/3093378)

Comment: Interesting, it compiles with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94b2c62b6d43059e) but not g++.

Comment: @T.C. hmmm, it is interesting. I don't know how I manage to come up with these examples, I'm just trying to polish up my C++ and end up coming with all these g++ vs clang++ issues recently :)

Comment: I think the overload resolution should be the same as `void f(test const&);` vs `void f(test const&&);`, and the latter should unambiguously win for rvalues. [over.match.funcs]/4-5 and [over.ics.rank]/3.1.3

Comment: @dyp, yeah that's what I though, it should be a better match, however not for g++...

Comment: I tried your code, it compiles fine with g++-4.8.1 maybe you are using and "older" g++ version?

Comment: Compiles and works with g++4.10 (w/ and w/o const). Probably a fixed compiler bug.

Comment: @TheMasterMaind, no, I'm using g++4.9.1

Comment: @TheMasterMaind With or without the `const`? With the `const` [it doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d921092510ba6a10) when I tested it on g++ 4.8.1.

Comment: Without the const. Okay I have to say that I dont used my PC, I compiled it on my Android smartphone.

Comment: @TheMasterMaind yeah without const it works, and I understand why. I didn't get why it doesn't WITH const.

Comment: OK, then I guess it is just a g++ bug that got fixed on g++ 4.10.

Comment: I just tested it with declaring with const. Just worked fine. Yeah maybe it's a bug in your revision of the gcc

Comment: @TheMasterMaind what compiler are you using? It seems it does not compile on any stable g++ version, only on clang. See http://goo.gl/YreY1H

Comment: Im using g++-4.8.1 posix on my Android device

Comment: OK, it is a bug in many g++ implementations then, just find out that the question has been asked before. Case closed :)

Comment: @vsoftco: please provide a link for future readers, thanks.

Comment: The link appears on the top of the page, but here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17130607/3093378