# Return of `const bool` causes warning C4180

Tags: c++

```
struct CCompare
{
    const bool operator()(const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};
```

> Warning   1   warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no
>   meaning;

I saw the usage with return value as `const bool` in a programming book. When I compiled the above code with vs2010, it reports the warning C4180.

The following code instead will not cause the same warning.

```
struct CCompare
{
    bool operator()(const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};
```

**Question1**> Is it true that the usage of `const Fundamental_Data_Types` as a function returned value doesn't make sense?

**Question2**> Is it true that the usage of `const Type` as a function returned value only makes sense iff the Type is a class/struct?

Thank you

// Update //

```
struct CClass
{
    int val;
    CClass(int _val) : val(_val) {}

    void SetValue(int _val) {
        val = _val;
    }
};

struct CCompare
{
    const CClass getMe() const {
        return CClass(10);
    }

    CClass getMeB() const {
        return CClass(10);
    }
};

int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/) 
{
    CCompare c;

    c.getMe().SetValue(20);   // error
    c.getMeB().SetValue(20);  // ok
}
```

Comment: In both cases, the return value is copied to the caller. You have no right to enforce `const` on a copied value they're getting back.

Comment: `const` only makes sense if you return a reference or a pointer, regardless of whether it is a class/struct or fundamental type.

Comment: @RogerRowland Refer to Effective C++ 3rd pp 18 `const Rational operator*(const Rational&, const Rational&);`

Comment: @q0987 Ok, but my copy is at home, so it will have to wait unless you can explain?

Comment: @RogerRowland That's not correct.  Think about calling a member function on the return value, e.g. `func1().func2()`.  If `func1` returns a const, then you can only call `func2` if it is const.

Comment: @JamesKanze so how does that make what I said wrong? Can you give another example? If I understand your comment, you mean calling a function on a returned temporary?

Comment: @RogerRowland, here is what Scott Meyers has to say. The `const` in front of `Rational` helps make the following code invalid. `Rational a, b, c; (a*b) = c;` and `if (a*b = c) // oops, meant to do a comparison`

Comment: @q0987 ah, ok, I've got it now - thanks for pointing that out, I should have thought more carefully (I've read those books so many times too!) ... FWIW, I don't get that warning on VS2012 even at max warning level.

Comment: @RogerRowland, That book just likes a bible and you can appreciate more when you read more:)

Comment: @q0987 lol - it's much more effective learning to get publicly corrected on SO ;-)

Comment: @q0987, That advice has been deprecated. The proper way to prevent that would be to make `operator=` only take lvalues, which you can do with rvalue references for `this`.

Comment: @chris The only way to ensure that a function only takes lvalues as it's left operand is to make it a free function, taking a non-const reference, e.g. `MyClass& operator+=( MyClass& lhs, MyClass const& rhs )`.  And `operator=` can't be a free function.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Shouldn't `MyClass &operator=(MyClass rhs) &;` do it?

Comment: @chris `MyClass& operator=( MyClass const& rhs );` won't compile unless it is a member, and if it is a member, there's no requirement that the left operand be an lvalue; you can call member functions on rvalues.

Comment: @JamesKanze, But you can specify `this` to be an lvalue with the [C++11 feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this), which is now starting to be supported among compilers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and yes to both of your questions.  Return values are
rvalues, and cv-qualifiers only apply to rvalues if they have
a class type.

The reason for this is fairly simple: there's normally nothing
you can do with an rvalue where const-ness would make
a difference—it's a value, after all, and not an object.
With a class type, there are member functions to take into
account (which means that you can get an lvalue from the
rvalue), so const-ness suddenly becomes relevant.

Comment: Can you detail why cv-qualifiers only apply to rvalues? `const int leftValue = 10`. Here the `const` is applied to a lvalue. I assume that I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @q0987 You're misreading me. `const` can apply to all lvalues.  It can only apply to rvalues if they have class type.