# How do "const", "&", and "&&" affect overloading of a parameterless function?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, rvalue-reference, member-functions

Consider a class defined as below:

```
struct A
{
    void f();
    void f() const;
    void f() &;
    void f() const &;
    void f() &&;
    void f() const &&;
};
```

What are the differences between:

**1) void A::f(); and void A::f() &; (Please notice this!)**

2) void A::f() const; and void A::f() const &;

3) void A::f() &&; and void A::f() const &&;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this . And you cannot have both ref-qualified functions and normal functions. It's either one or another.

Comment: Petr's comment should be the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform these to

```
void f(A&);
void f(const A&);

void f(A&);
void f(const A&);
void f(A&&) &&;
void f(const A&&);
```

The first is special - it is a `A&`, *but still accepts rvalues*, unlike other non-const lvalue references. In all other regards, it is the same as any other function with a `A&` parameter.

There is no difference in overload resolution between the second (`const`) and the fourth (`const&)`, except if they respectively compete against a (`&&`). I don't think that can happen for normal functions, but only for conversion functions, because the Standard forbids this case (in general, if there is any function in the current scope with a ref qualifier, all functions must)

```
void f();
void f() &&;
```

But with conversion functions, you can still have an overload resolution set with both `operator int()` and `operator long()&&`. In that case, even if the object on which they are invoked is `R()` (an rvalue), if you need to convert to `int` then the first conversion function would be used.

Answer (score 1):

1. `f()` is a normal function for `f() const`, `this` must point to a modifiable lval
2. `f() const` is a const function (cannot change this) `f() const &`is the same but guarantees this is an lval as well
3. `f()&&` this must be a temporary value for `f() const &&` this must be a temporary value that you cannot modify