# std::forward of a function passed via universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference

Consider the two following:

```
template <class Function>
void apply(Function&& function)
{
    std::forward<Function>(function)();
}
```

and

```
template <class Function>
void apply(Function&& function)
{
    function();
}
```

In what case is there a difference, and what concrete difference is it ?

Comment: search for "perfect forwarding C++11"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a difference if `Function`'s `operator()` has ref qualifiers. With `std::forward`, the value category of the argument is propagated, without it, the value category is lost, and the function will always be called as an l-value. [Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a77a5c6161e35a72).

```
#include <iostream>

struct Fun {
    void operator()() & {
        std::cout << "L-Value\n";
    }
    void operator()() && {
        std::cout << "R-Value\n";
    }
};

template <class Function>
void apply(Function&& function) {
    function();
}

template <class Function>
void apply_forward(Function&& function) {
    std::forward<Function>(function)();
}

int main () {
    apply(Fun{});         // Prints "L-Value\n"
    apply_forward(Fun{}); // Prints "R-Value\n"
}
```

Comment: Since when can one apply ref qualifiers to member function declarations?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Since 2011.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Since `C++11`. The functionality is described in [n2439](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm). See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8610571/485561).

Comment: You should probably mention that this is because the parameter is named, and as soon as it has a name it will be treated as an L-value unless you `forward` it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the background. If i see it right the single `&`-qualifier on the function is just for symmetry and emphasis.