# Is there any real use case for function's reference qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, ref-qualifier, function-qualifier

Recently I learned about `function's reference qualifiers`, e.g.

```
struct foo
{
    void bar() {}
    void bar1() & {}
    void bar2() && {}
};
```

Where I might need this feature, is there any real use case for this language feature ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this

Comment: The most useful way I know is using for *convertion operator* overloading `struct foo { operator std::string () const & { return s; } operator std::string () && { return std::move(s); } std::string s; };`. Therefore `foo func() { return {"string"s}; } ... std::string s = foo();` not imply unnecessary copying and destruction of nonempty `std::string` object.

Comment: @Orient please add this as an answer as it's really interesting and might be helpful for somebody.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are basically two uses:

1. To provide an optimized overload, for example to move a member out of a temporary object instead of having to copy it.
2. Prevent misuse of an API. For example, no one would expect

   ```
   int a = 1 += 2;
   ```

   to work and this would also cause a compile error. However

   ```
   string b = string("foo") += "bar";
   ```

   is legal if `operator +=` is declared as

   ```
   string & operator += (string const & o);
   ```

   as is usually the case. Also this has the nasty side-effect of providing an lvalue-reference to your rvalue. Bad idea. This can easily be prevented by declaring the operator as

   ```
   string & operator += (string const & o) &;
   ```

Answer (score 29):

> Where I might need this feature, is there any real use case for this language feature ?

The example you show is pretty useless, it's more useful when you have an overloaded function, one version that operates on lvalues and one that operates on rvalues.

Consider a type a bit like `std::stringstream` that owns a string and returns it by value. If the object is an rvalue, it can move the string instead of copying it.

```
class StringBuilder
{
public:
  std::string get() const& { return m_str; }
  std::string get() && { return std::move(m_str); }

private:
  std::string m_str;
};
```

This means when you return a `StringBuilder` from a function and want to get the string out of it, you don't need a copy:

```
std::string s = buildString().get();
```

More generally, given a function `f(const X&)` if it would be useful to overload it with `f(X&&)`, then given a member function `X::f()` it *might* be useful to change it to `X::f() const&` and overload it with `X::f()&&`