# C++ overload () operator, lvalue and rvalue

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

Consider the following simple class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
  int* myvar;
  int sz;

  test()
  {
    sz = 10;
    myvar = new int[10];
  }

  void dump()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
      cout << myvar[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  int& operator()(int index)
  {
    if(index >= sz)
    {
      int* newvar = new int[index+1];

      for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
      {
        newvar[i] = myvar[i];
      }
      sz = index+1;
      delete myvar;
      myvar = newvar;
    }
    return myvar[index];
  }

  const int operator()(int index) const
  {
    if(index >= sz)
    {
      throw "index exceeds dimension";
    }
    else
    {
      return myvar[index];
    }
  }
};
```

It should behave like a dynamic array. I overloaded the () operator. My idea was, that for an assignment (lvalue), the upper version of the () will be called, and for a "read only" operation (rvalue) the lower version of () is used. The sample code should explain more clearly what I mean:

```
int main()
{
  test x;

  // will give 10 times zero
  x.dump();

  // assign some values
  x(1) = 7;
  x(9) = 99;

  // will give
  // 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99
  x.dump();

  // should give 7
  cout << x(1) << endl;

  // should give 99
  cout << x(9) << endl;

  // this will increase the size of myvar to 15 elements and assign a value
  x(15) = 15;

  // this should give
  // 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 0 0 0 0 0 15
  x.dump();

  // this should throw an exception because x(20) got never assigned a value!
  // but instead of calling the lower version of operator() it also calls the
  // upper, resulting in x being expanded now to 21 elements.
  cout << x(20) << endl;

  // will give 21 elements, instead of 16.
  x.dump();

  return 0;
}
```

So I access the contents of `myvar` via the () operator. It should be possible to assign a value just to *any* element, but it shall not be possible to query the value of an element that has never been set before. I thought by using different versions of (), one of which being `const` should suffice, but apparently, the compiler is always using the upper version of my operator, and never the lower. How can I fix this problem?

I read about the proxy object, e.g [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762323/6120450), but I think this implementation will not work in my case because I am using an array. So
a) is it possible without the proxy, or if not
b) how should the proxy look like in my case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026352/is-there-any-real-use-case-for-functions-reference-qualifiers

Comment: Which overload of `operator()` is called only depends on what `x` is. In your case, `x` is the same for all calls to `operator()` so the same overload is always called, and the standard says that in this case it's the non-`const` qualified. You clearly need a proxy in this case.

Comment: sure, x is the very same object in both situations, but in the first case, an assignment is made to x. In this situation, the value of x may be changed so its perfectly fine if the non-const version of the operator is called. But in the latter case, x is only read and thus its value cannot change, therefore it would be intuitive that the const operator is called!

Comment: @T.Pluess No assignment is made to `x`, assignment is made to the return value of `x(...)`, which is not `x`.

Comment: sure. So how do I use the proxy in this situation?

Comment: @T.Pluess Something like that: https://godbolt.org/z/MY52OR

Comment: that worked for me. Do you want to post an answer, such that I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the solution I finally came up with (sort of):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class myclass
{
private:
  unsigned numel;
  T* elem;

public:

  class proxy
  {
    private:

        T*& elem;
        unsigned& numel;
        const unsigned index;

        proxy(T*& elem, unsigned& numel, unsigned index) : elem(elem), numel(numel), index(index) { }

        // didn't really need those two
        // proxy(const proxy&) = default;
        // proxy(proxy&&) = default;

        friend class myclass;

    public:
        proxy& operator=(const T& value)
        {
          if(index >= numel)
          {
            cout << "assignment to an element outside the range!" << endl;
            cout << "old size: " << numel << endl;
            cout << "new size: " << index+1 << endl << endl;

            T* newelem = new T[index+1];
            for(unsigned i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            {
              if(i < this->numel)
              {
                newelem[i] = this->elem[i];
              }
              else
              {
                newelem[i] = 0;
              }
            }

            if(this->elem != nullptr)
            {
              delete this->elem;
            }
            this->elem = newelem;
            this->numel = index+1;
          }

          this->elem[index] = value;
          return *this;
        }

        proxy& operator=(const proxy &other)
        {
          *this = (const T&)other;
          return *this;
        }

        operator T&()
        {
          if(index >= numel)
          {
            cout << "cannot query the value of elements outside the range!" << endl;
            cout << "# of elements: " << numel << endl;
            cout << "index requested: " << index << endl << endl;

            throw out_of_range("");
          }
          return elem[index];
        }

        operator const T&() const
        {
          if(index >= numel)
          {
            throw out_of_range("");
          }
          return elem[index];
        }
    };

  myclass() : numel(0), elem(nullptr) {};

  myclass(unsigned count)
  {
    this->numel = count;
    this->elem = new T[count];
  }

  ~myclass()
  {
    if(this->elem != nullptr)
    {
      delete this->elem;
    }
  }


  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const myclass& mc)
  {
    os << endl;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mc.numel; i++)
    {
      os << mc.elem[i] << "  ";
      os << endl;
    }
    os << endl;
    return os;
  }

  proxy operator()(unsigned index)
  {
    return proxy(this->elem, this->numel, index);
  }

};


int main()
{
  myclass<double> my;

  my(1) = 77;
  my(0) = 200;
  my(8) = 12;

  cout << my;

  try
  {
    cout << my(0) << endl;
    cout << my(1) << endl;
    cout << my(8) << endl;
    cout << my(10) << endl;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    cout << "error catched" << endl << endl;
  }

  my(10) = 10101;

  cout << my(10) << endl;

}
```

the output on the terminal looks like this:

```
assignment to an element outside the range!
old size: 0
new size: 2

assignment to an element outside the range!
old size: 2
new size: 9


200  
77  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
0  
12  

200
77
12
cannot query the value of elements outside the range!
# of elements: 9
index requested: 10

error catched

assignment to an element outside the range!
old size: 9
new size: 11

10101
```