# const& , & and && specifiers for member functions in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

Recently I was reading through the [API of `boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) and came across the lines:

```
T const& operator *() const& ;
T&       operator *() & ;
T&&      operator *() && ;
```

I also wrote my own program  that defines member functions as const&, & and && (Note that I am not speaking about the return type, but the specifiers just before the semi-colons) and they seems to work fine.

I know what it means to declare a member function const, but can anyone explain what it means to declare it  const&, & and &&.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`const&` means that this overload will be used only for const, non-const and lvalue objects, such as:

```cpp
const A a = A();
*a;
```

`&` means that this overload will be used only for non-const objects:

```cpp
A a;
*a;
```

`&&` means that this overload will be used only for rvalue objects:

```cpp
*A();
```

For more information about this feature of the C++11 standard you can read this post: [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)

Comment: If it helps, I like to think of these qualifiers as applying to the `*this` object that is "secretly" passed in as the first argument of methods.

Comment: `const&` and `&` mean they will be used for a `const` and non-`const` *lvalue*. `&&` will be used only for an rvalue, not necessarily a reference.

Comment: Actually, the `const &` can bind to pretty much anything, even an rvalue. Similar rules as apply to the binding of any parameter - `const T&` is kinda special - it can bind to anything that isn't `volatile` IIRC

Comment: Thanks. Understood on a superficial level. Can you explain why this 3rd overload is necessary. I am guessing that they created this third overload so that a value can be moved out of the optional or any such structure while using * operator if the structure is created as an rvalue reference. But can't the compiler deduce automatically that the structure containing the member variable is an rvalue reference

Comment: @john_zac You're right in why they did it, and no, a compiler cannot introduce `std::move`s as it sees fit. It could break the class's invariants, RAII semantics etc. The only place in the standard where something similar is allowed is `return`, where returning as an rvalue is tried first.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Wow, this never really dawned on me.

Comment: @john_zac, these aren't quite "necessary", as you ask. But they provide certain optional optimizations. You could get away with just having `T operator *();` - this would compile but it would have some weird consequences - `*p = x` wouldn't do what you expect it to do. I think the important thing is the return type - we want multiple overloads with different return types. Once you understand the desirability of different return types, then you see also that we need the qualifiers on the end to control which overload (and therefore which return type) is used for each call.

Comment: @Agnew. I think I understand. It is kind of analoguous to the case where we always need to explicity use 'std::move' to move member variables inside a move constructor

Comment: Ever tried calling a `&`-member on a `const` object? It does not work.

Answer (score 51):

It is a member function ref-qualifiers; it is one of the features added in C++11. It is possible to overload non-static member functions based on whether the implicit `this` object parameter is an lvalue or an rvalue by specifying a function ref-qualifier ([some details](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)).

To specify a ref-qualifier for a non-static member function, you can either qualify the function with `&` or `&&`.

```
#include <iostream>
struct myStruct {
    void func() & { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
    void func() &&{ std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }
};
 
int main(){
    myStruct s;
    s.func();            // prints "lvalue"
    std::move(s).func(); // prints "rvalue"
    myStruct().func();   // prints "rvalue"
}
```

Comment: any use case for  myStruct().func();  over  s.func();? @Alper