# Method call acting unexpectedly like an l-value

Tags: c++

Can anybody explain why [this code](http://ideone.com/lnUswp) compiles:

```
typedef struct longlong
{
  unsigned long low;
  long high;
}
longlong;

typedef longlong Foo;    

struct FooStruct
{
private:
  Foo bar;

public:
  void SetBar(Foo m)
  {
    bar = m;
  }

  Foo GetBar()
  {
    return bar;
  }
};

int main()
{
  FooStruct f;
  Foo m1 = { 1,1 };
  Foo m2 = { 2,2 };
  f.SetBar(m1);
  f.GetBar() = m2;     // Here I'd expect an error such as
                       // "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"
}
```

I expected the compilation to fail with `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` on line `f.GetBar() = m2;` because IMO `f.GetBar()` is not an l-value, but it compiles seemlessly and `f.GetBar() = m2;` is a NOP.

On the other hand if I replace the `typedef longlong Foo;` by `typedef long Foo;`, the line mentioned before won't compile and I get the expected error.

I came along this issue while refactoring some old code. The code in this question has no purpose other than to illustrate this issue.

Comment: I was curious whether this issue exists in Rust, so I wrote up a [quick example](https://github.com/BatmanAoD/rust-sandbox/blob/master/retval_assign.rs). It does not; the example fails to compile, stating that the assignment is improper.

Comment: This issue also [does not affect C](http://rextester.com/MSCPGT70980), so it is in fact an incompatibility in the C-subset of C++ (!!). (In the linked example, switching from C to C++ prevents an error from being emitted.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reasons for this behavior were described in other answers.

One way to avoid this behavior would be qualifying your return type with `const`:

```
struct FooStruct
{
    ...
    const Foo GetBar() {return bar;}
};
```

You cannot assign values to `const` objects, so the compiler will complain.

Answer (score 12):

This works because `longlong` is a class, and as such `=` is `longlong::operator =`, the implicitly-defined assignment operator. And you *can* call member functions on temporaries as long as they're not qualified with `&` (the default `operator =` is unqualified).

To restrict the assignment operator to lvalues, you can explicitly default it with an additional ref-qualifier:

```
struct longlong
{
    longlong &operator = (longlong const &) & = default;
    //                                      ^

    // ...
};
```

Comment: This sounds convincing. But what can I do so `f.GetBar() = m2;` won't compile. I'd need that for my refactoring process.

Comment: `delete` the assignment operator?

Comment: Qualify `operator=` with `&`. As stated in ^.

Comment: @GillBates: Yes that would be better than my sledgehammer idea.

Comment: @MichaelWalz `Foo &operator = (Foo const &) & = default;`, note the `&` :)

Comment: @Quentin What does the `&` after parameter mean?

Comment: @Quentin unfortunately, `= default` cannot be used on ref-qualified functions

Comment: @VINOTHENERGETIC the parameter? That's your plain old reference-to-const, from the usual copy-assignment signature.

Comment: @VINOTHENERGETIC It means that that method is only used if `this` is `&`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066777/const-and-specifiers-for-member-functions-in-c

Comment: @M.M mmh, [works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a09a75ff1964d6d3), `-pedantic-error` and all. Would that be a compiler bug?

Comment: @Quentin Hmm.. I tried on several compilers (incl gcc 7.1 and 8) and it told me I couldn't, but clearly I did not try the version you used there :) I guess someone will have to trawl the standard to resolve this

Comment: @M.M got it! [dcl.fct.def.default](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.default): "A function that is explicitly defaulted shall [...] have the same declared function type (**except for possibly differing ref-qualifiers** [...]) as if it had been implicitly declared[.]". So this is fine :)

Comment: @anatolyg thanks, I was just checking that it is actually standard before lifting it in :)

Comment: @Quentin Good job. Looks like that's been in there for a while so it seems to be a long-standing bug that gcc doesn't accept it

Comment: I suppose the move-assignment operator should also get the same treatment

Answer (score 5):

Using operators on objects of class type means to call a function (either a member function of the left-hand operand, or a free function taking the left-hand operand as first argument). This is known as *operator overloading*.

It's fine to call functions on rvalues so there is no compilation error.

When implementing the overloaded assignment operator,  you can mark it so that it can not be called on an rvalue, but the designer of whatever class you are using chose not to do that.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>   f.GetBar() = m2;     // Here I'd expect an error such as
>                        // "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"
> ```

Your expectation is in error. This rule only applies to objects of built-in type.

> `[C++14: 3.10/5]:` An lvalue for an object is necessary in order to modify the object except that an rvalue of class type can also be used to modify its referent under certain circumstances. *[ Example:* a member function called for an object (9.3) can modify the object. *—end example ]*

Recall that your `=` here is actually a call to `operator=`, which is a function.