# What is `&` in `function() const &` in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example:

```
constexpr T value_or(U&& v) const &
```

What is `&` after `const`?

and sometimes I also see `&&` after `const`, what is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [const& , & and && specifiers for member functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066777/const-and-specifiers-for-member-functions-in-c)

Comment: yes、please mark as duplicated. thanks