# Why can an object with deleted copy- and move-constructor still be passed to a function accepting an r-value reference?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have the following code, which apparently compiles in MSVC and GCC:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
  Test() = default;
  Test(Test const& other) = delete;
  Test(Test&& other) noexcept = delete;

  Test& operator=(Test const& other) = delete;
  Test& operator=(Test&& other) = delete;

  auto getX() -> int
  {
    return x;
  };
  auto setX(int xz) -> void
  {
    x = xz;
  };

private:
  int x = 42;
};

void something(Test&& thing) {
  thing.setX(44);
  std::cout << thing.getX() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Test a;
  a.setX(3);
  std::cout << "Before call: " << a.getX() << std::endl;
  something(std::move(a));
  std::cout << "After call: " << a.getX() << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I would have expected this to not compile. Both the move and the copy constructor of Test are deleted. The function `something` only accepts r-value references. However, it does compile, and this is the output of the program:

```
Before call: 3
44
After call: 44
```

The only way that I could think of how it should be possible to pass an object of type Test to a function is by using an l-value reference or const ref. But the way `something` is defined, it should only accept rvalues, shouldn't it?

Here is the code on compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/rGKdGbsM5

Comment: you cannot prevent someone from getting a reference to an object

Comment: Learn this [const& , & and && specifiers for member functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066777/const-and-specifiers-for-member-functions-in-c)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks for the answer. I know that move only casts the object to an rvalue-reference. My misconception was how the argument is passed to a function expecting a && argument. I would have assumed that the argument is moved inside. Instead it is passed as a reference. The only significance of the && in the function signature is that only r-values bind to this overload. If you like you can add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rvalue references are just references just like lvalue references. The difference between them is the kind of expression that can be used to initialize them.

`std::move` casts an lvalue reference to an rvalue reference. It doesn't require the type to be movable. If you try to actually move `thing` in `something` then you will get errors.