# When should I use const& to this?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, this

I found some code like this:

```
class foo{
    int a;
public:
    foo(int v) : a{v} {}
    bool operator==(const foo& rhs) const&{
        return (rhs.a == a);
    }
};
```

It compiles and runs.

I was wondering what are the benefits (or drawbacks) of having the reference (&) to this in the operator==.

Comment: That actually compiles! Mind blown >.< http://ideone.com/rOIrqE

Comment: @NeilKirk Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @T.C. I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this

Comment: For non-`const` member functions, `&` prevents it from being called on rvalues. For `const` member functions there's not much difference, except that you can write a `&&` version that will be preferentially called for rvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As T.C. has been pointing out in comments, this reason for this is NOT "to accept only lvalues".  `const` references bind to rvalues just fine.

The reason for it is that functions can be overloaded on value category of the implicit object parameter only if ALL overloads specify a value category.  That is, when you add an overload with `&&` that matches only rvalues, it won't compile unless you add `&` to the existing overload.

In 13.1, here is the wording of the rule:

> Member  function  declarations  with  the  same  name  and  the  same  *parameter-type-list*  as  well  as  member function template declarations with the same name, the same *parameter-type-list*, and the same
>   template parameter lists cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not all, have a *ref-qualifier*.

and gives an example

> ```
> class  Y
> {
>    void  h()  &;
>    void  h()  const  &;        // OK
>    void  h()  &&;              // OK, all declarations have a ref-qualifier
>    void  i()  &;
>    void  i()  const;           // ill-formed, prior declaration of  i
>                                // has a ref-qualifier
> };
> ```

Comment: Heh, I wrote `*this`...yes, `*this` is always an lvalue.

Comment: @T.C.: Doh!  Your edit comment makes perfect sense then.

Comment: vote up.Combining T.C. comment and your answer,that will be a perfect answer.