# What are reference qualifiers for functions?

Tags: c++, c++11

According to [this webpage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), a non-static member function can have a trailing `&` or `&&` in its declaration. They have the following example

```
struct S {
    virtual int f(char) const, g(int) &&; // declares two non-static member functions
    };
```

1) Does the signature of the second function include the `virtual`?

```
virtual int g(int) &&
```

2) What is the meaning of the trailing `&&`?

Comment: Please create two different questions for the two different questions in your text.

Comment: `&&` is for the r-value reference for '`*this`'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct S {
  virtual int f(char) const, g(int) &&;
};

struct D : S {
  virtual int f(char) const override;
  virtual int g(int) && override;
};
```

the above code compiles in both [g++ and clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ba3b54300f72997).  This indicates, at least in practice, that `g` is `virtual` in `S`.

See [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610571/1774667) for your other question.

Comment: Good use of `override` there! I was going to confirm by testing if a pointer-to-base would call the correct `g`, but this is much better!