# Perfect forwarding a functor

Tags: c++, templates, functor, perfect-forwarding

I wonder what's the right way of using a perfect forwarded functor? Here's two code snippet. Which one is the best, and if neither, what is the best form?

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void callMe(T&& func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Or

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void callMe(T&& func, Args&&... args) {
    std::forward<T>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

EDIT:

Will it impact overload resolution? If `func`'s `operator()` has ref-qualifier for `&&` or `const &`, should I do the latter version and should I care about which overload I call?

Thanks!

Comment: The latter is correct if the function call operator may have a ref-qualifier

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @JohanLundberg http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2114bc29d189fde9

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since ref-qualified `operator()` exists, the first version could do the wrong thing. Consider:

```
struct C {
    void operator()() && { std::cout << "rval\n"; }
    void operator()() const & { std::cout << "lval\n"; }
};

callMe(C{});
```

I'm giving you an rvalue - and would expect to see `"rval"` - but in the first version, you're always treating the function object like an lvalue - so I really see `"lval"`.

So the correct solution would be the second - which `forward`s `func` as well.

---

In practice, I don't know how often ref-qualified member functions actually happen, so the former is likely fine.

Comment: Cool. I had no idea ref-qualification existed.

Comment: The fear I'd have is an optimization of lambda, where rvalue lambdas start implicitly moving from their stored internal state like local variables.  This could give you some nice performance boosts in some cases maybe, and lacking the forward would be lost.  But probably not.

Comment: @Yakk I read that as "it's probably impossible to correctly write generic code in C++"

Answer (score 5):

Perfect forwarding is useful in the case where you are going to *deliver* an object (possibly an rvalue) to some other function, and you're not sure if it's an rvalue or an lvalue. In this case, you just *use* `func`, so there's no gain or harm in forwarding it.

Remember, `std::forward` is a conditional `std::move`, which is only a cast to an r-value reference.

In addition, it's really only useful if there's a possibility that a copy or move constructor might be called for the thing you forward. In many cases, `const T&` will do just fine.

**edit:**

As berry points out, it *does* matter if `func` has ref-qualified `operator()`. I've never seen or used a ref qualified method (as far as I know. It's extremely rare.) More in Barry's answer.

It'd read this also: [What is "rvalue reference for *this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)

```
struct C {
    void operator()() && { std::cout << "rval\n"; }
    void operator()() const & { std::cout << "lval\n"; }
};

callMe(C{});
```

Comment: +1 agreed. For other readers, I'd like to point out that there's no harm in forwarding it if you're only going to use it because `std::forward` is merely a typecast to r-value reference (`&&`) or l-value reference (`&`).

Comment: Disagree on "gain/harm". What if `T` has ref-qualified `operator()`?