# Differentiate conversion operator template for reference and non-reference types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, conversion-operator

I have a `struct InferValueType` which shall be implicitly convertible to any other type including reference types. I accomplish this using the following code.

```
struct InferValueType {
    // ...

    template <typename Type>
    operator Type() const && {
        // ...
    }

    // We need this special version to allow conversions to reference types
    template <typename Type>
    operator Type&() const & {
        // ...
    }
};
```

`InferValueType` is never instantiated by the the user, instead I provide it as the return value of a function.

```
const InferValueType read();
```

The combination of `InferValueType` and `read` allows the user to write lazy code like this:

```
int i = read();
MyType t1 = read();
MyType& t2 = read();
const MyType& t3 = read();
```

I have tested this against GCC 4.8, 4.9, 5, 6 and Clang 3.7 and 3.8. Only GCC 4.8 complains about an ambiguity.

```
conversion from ‘const InferValueType’ to ‘int’ is ambiguous
conversion from ‘const InferValueType’ to ‘MyType’ is ambiguous
```

I assume this is because `int` and `MyType` can be constructed using `const int&` and `const MyType&` respectively.

**Question:** Is this a peculiarity of GCC before 4.9.2 or is it actually an ambiguity under C++11?

Complete example is [here](https://gist.github.com/vapourismo/ee4c873cd87bb9a58dfce2fa2926bc98).

Comment: What's the point of const && ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this
Please show more code, including constructors.

Comment: I'd be curious to see what you are planning to return from `operator Type&()`. Who's going to manage the lifetime of the `Type` object that the reference refers to?

Comment: https://github.com/vapourismo/luwra/blob/master/lib/luwra/stack.hpp#L46

Comment: `const &&` is used because the the conversion operator is not directly overloadable for `Type` and `Type`

Comment: No special constructor is involved: https://github.com/vapourismo/luwra/blob/master/lib/luwra/values.hpp#L42

Comment: As far as I can tell: `InferValueType::operator T&()` returns `Value<Type&>::read()`. `Value<Type&>` is effectively synonymous with `Value<Type>`, and its `read()` returns `Type` temporary, by value. Put together, `InferValueType::operator T&()` returns a dangling reference (which used to refer to a temporary that has already been destroyed); any attempt to use this reference would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik https://github.com/vapourismo/luwra/blob/master/lib/luwra/usertypes.hpp#L145

Comment: @M.M I've added the example. What do you intend to accomplish with it?

Comment: @Vapou compile and execute it and observe the behaviour you are claiming