# Why is `f().items()` wrong in the range-based for statement with initializer example

Tags: c++, c++20

In [his report on the Fall 2017 standards meeting](https://herbsutter.com/2017/11/11/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-albuquerque/), Herb Sutter has the following example of what the range-based for statement with initializer is simplifying:

```
{
  T thing = f();
  for (auto& x : thing.items()) {
    // Note: “for (auto& x : f().items())” is WRONG
    mutate(&x);
    log(x);
  }
}
```

Why is `for (auto& x : f().items())` wrong? That is, when does `f().items()` yield undefined behavior but `T thing = f(); ... thing.items()` not yield it?

(This question [might be considered a duplicate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955021/309334) was only revealed by writing the question, not by normal search, so I decided it was worthwhile including in StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 3):

If `t.items()` returns a reference to a member of `t`, then `f().items()` will give you a dangling reference and thus undefined behavior.

Breaking it down: `f()` will be a temporary that will be destroyed after the `items()` call returns. If `items()` returns a reference to a member of that temporary, it will become dangling once the temporary is destroyed.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40955021/309334 for more detail and a way of writing your methods so they won't have this problem.