# ELI5 What is the meaning '&&' keyword after a function name

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I met this code and i dont know what is this, can someone explain to me?

```
template<class T> base{

protected:

T data;

public:

...

T&& unwrap() && { return std::move(data); }

operator T&&() && { return std::move(data); }

}
```

I know `operator T&&()` is a [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) but i cant figure out what is the meaning of the bold **&&** in:

> operator T&&() **&&**
>   or
>   T&& unwrap() **&&**

Comment: Those are [*ref-qualified* function specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions).

Comment: There is a nice example in the (currently accepted) answer to [SO: What is “rvalue reference for *this”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8610728/7478597) which appears a bit more practical to me like the one on cppreference...

Comment: OT: ELI5 ... Explain like I'm 5. IMHO, 5 is too young to learn C++...

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` and `&` qualifiers on a member function like that indicates the following:

- The `&` qualified function will be called on lvalue instances of the object
- The `&&` qualified function will be called on rvalue instances of the object

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>

class Example
{
private:
    int whatever = 0;

public:
    Example() = default;

    // Lvalue ref qualifier
    void getWhatever() & { std::cout << "This is called on lvalue instances of Example\n"; }

    // Rvalue ref qualifier
    void getWhatever() && { std::cout << "This is called on rvalue instances of Example\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // Create example
    Example a;

    // Calls the lvalue version of the function since it's called on an lvalue
    a.getWhatever();

    // Calls rvalue version by making temporary
    Example().getWhatever();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
This is called on lvalue instances of Example
This is called on rvalue instances of Example
```

Since in the first function call we are calling it on an lvalue instance of `Example`, but in the second call we are making it a temporary on which we call the function, invoking the rvalue qualified function.