Why does direct initialization use a const lvalue reference qualified conversion function?
I have two classes st and foo:
struct st {
    st() = default;

    st(const st&) {
        std::cout << "copy ctor." << std::endl;
    }

    st(st&&) {
        std::cout << "move ctor." << std::endl;
    }
};

struct foo {
    operator st&() & {
        return s;
    }

    operator const st&() const& {
        return s;
    }

    operator st&&() && {
        return std::move(s);
    }

    operator const st&&() const&& {
        return std::move(s);
    }

    st s;
};

When I run code like this:
st s = st(foo());

It calls the copy constructor of st.
Why does it not call foo's rvalue-reference-qualified conversion function and use st's move constructor?

EDIT:

MSVC can compile this, but GCC and Clang cannot.
If I remove const & operator, then MSVC, GCC, Clang can compile.
If I remove && operator, then MSVC and GCC can compile, but Clang cannot.
If I remove && operator and const && operator, then MSVC, GCC, Clang can compile.


does not compile for me: https://godbolt.org/z/3ePa8fEM4

Reference collapsing? And since it builds with MSVC, perhaps they have a special rule for it? Or a bug? Or something else?

@NathanOliver I use MSVC and can compile

I'm totally confused.  I can't understand why it fails to compile, I don't understand the reason for ambiguity error. OTOH I would expect a move to happen and not a copy.  Wish I could help more, maybe someone else will know.  One thing to note is that clang specifically calls out the function style cast.  Maybe there are different rules that apply in that situation ¯\(ツ)/¯

With st s = foo(); it builds with all three compilers, and also works and uses the move constructor (proof).

@Someprogrammerdude In fact, I would use something like s(std::forward<T>(t)) to initialize members. Here is just an example to reproduce the problem

@NathanOliver -- as far as I can see, it fails because there are two conversion paths, foo->const st& and foo->st&& and the two corresponding constructors

@Gene From my reading foo can only be converted to st&& since the const st& overload is lvalue qualified and foo() is an rvalue.

@NathanOliver -- compilers disagree https://godbolt.org/z/PW3oc5oWsj

Btw, MSVC is the only one that differs (buggy), choosing copy ctor.

@Gene Neat, now it is even more confusing.  The compiler should not be able to call an lvalue qualified function on an rvalue.  Hopefully someone will have an answer.

@Gene It's not just MSVC that is different, see my edit

@ ValueError -- clang has a bug too, gcc got it right in every case

@Gene Can you explain why GCC is right?

@ ValueError -- (const) rvalue reference can be bound to const lvalue reference

@Gene Your godbolt link doesn't seem to work. I get 'Whoops, ID "PW3oc5oWsj" couldn't be found'

@François Andrieux -- weird, I think it was this, binding to const lvalue reference  https://godbolt.org/z/qjPocs9oG

Bottom line, const lvalue reference is a universal sink -- binds to everything

@Gene [Insert pedantic statement about references to volatile].

@François Andrieux -- I keep forgetting, C++ has volatile

@Gene So for this situation, the overload resolution doesn't think rvalue-reference-qualified function is better than const-lvalue-reference-qualified function?

@FrançoisAndrieux I don't see why one conversion would have a higher ranking than the others https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.funcs.general#4.sentence-1 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3.2.3 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3.2.6?

@NathanOliver "The compiler should not be able to call an lvalue qualified function on an rvalue." Not so if the function is const lvalue qualified.

@FrançoisAndrieux "foo() is an xvalue..." No, foo() is a prvalue.

@user12002570 I think he means the [expr.ref] context https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.temporary#2.2

@LanguageLawyer Yeah, but that still means that foo()  was originally a prvalue. In certain contexts, like here it can be converted to xvalue. But at the starting that construct is still an prvalue.

Overloading conversion operator ambiguous error

@user12002570 IMO the duplicate is insufficient as it doesn't address why rvalue and lvalue qualifiers don't solve the ambiguity.

@FrançoisAndrieux Because both && and const& ref qualifier versions are viable for foo() and  so here we'll still use different conversion operators.

@user12002570 But that isn't addressed by the duplicate, and seems like a likely cause of confusion. This chain of comments seems to show that.

@WeijunZhou There is no const & qualifier.  The only reference qualifiers are & and &&.  See: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct

@NathanOliver A member function that is both const-qualified and lref-qualified can be called on rvalue objects. I'm sure this has been asked before on SO.

@WeijunZhou Looks like that is the case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427227/lvalue-ref-qualified-member-function-being-called-on-an-rvalue-object.  I'll need to keep this in mind going forward

Another Dupe: LValue ref qualified member function being called on an RValue object

Calling the copy constructor is wrong. The compiler is not following the specification.
The call is ill-formed, because overload resolution should be ambiguous.
The problem is quite generally that if you have two viable overloads, in this case the constructors
st(const st&);

and
st(st&&);

and both overloads require a user-defined conversion sequence in the argument where both use a different conversion function or constructor, the two conversion sequences are always considered equally good. How good the standard conversion sequences and the reference binding involved are, is only considered if the two user-defined conversion sequences would use the same conversion operator or constructor.

It might not be clear why both conversion operators are eligible candidates. foo()  is a prvalue which seems like it would exclude the lvalue ref qualified operators.

@FrançoisAndrieux As always, a rvalue can bind to const&, so the conversion operator with that qualification is viable.

Based on the comments, I think there is a common incorrect belief ref qualifiers have different rules than the typical rules for reference binding and that lvalue ref qualified functions can't be used with an rvalue at all.

@FrançoisAndrieux I don't think there is any such "common" misunderstanding. A const lvaue ref is also viable option for rvalues.

@user17732522 This answer doesn't explain why st s = foo() and st s(foo()) works. I mean reading this answer seems to imply that both of these should also be rejected.

@Alan st s = foo() is different, but st s(foo()) and st s = st(foo()); are the same and my answer applies. I also saw only one of the forms in the question.

This is also not a language-lawyered answer.

@NathanOliver Yes, and I am talking about the qualification of the member function, which for the purpose of overload resolution becomes the qualification of the implicit object parameter. Overload resolution then works (almost) as if it was a normal reference parameter with this qualification. In particular if the left-hand operand of the member access is a rvalue expression, it can bind to the const&-qualified implicit object parameter.

I probably understand that for the overload resolution of st(...), the ref-qualifier of foo's cast operator does not make move constructor better than copy constructor (and vice versa), so the call is ambiguous. Is that so?

@ValueError Yes, because the move constructor would use a different conversion function than the copy constructor would, neither conversion sequence is considered better than the other. The reference qualifications on the conversion function or the constructors' parameters are not considered to make a decision one way or the other. And because the two constructors also have no other difference that would make one preferred over the other, the overload resolution is ambiguous.

@ValueError Specifically, you fail to distinguish a preferred overload via https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.3, which requires the same conversion function for each candidate. If you then go through the rest of https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3 and https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-2 you won't find any rule making one of the overloads better than the other.
