# Return rvalue reference or temporary object in C++11

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

In **Effective Modern C++** *item 12*, there is a sample code about the **C++11 functions' reference qualifiers**:

```
class Widget {
public:
    using DataType = std::vector<double>;
    …
    DataType& data() &            // for lvalue Widgets
    { return values; }            // return lvalue

    DataType data() &&            // for rvalue Widgets
    { return std::move(values); } // return rvalue
    …
private:
    DataType values;
};
```

So why does the second `data()` **rvalue reference overload function** return a **temporary object** `DataType` but not an **rvalue reference** `DataType&&`?

Answer (score 6):

The only reason I see would be to avoid creation of dangling reference when the object is the result of a prvalue:

```
Widget foo();

auto&& x = foo().data();
```

If `foo().data()` returned an rvalue reference to `values` member, `x` would be a dangling reference, because the result object of `foo()` is destroyed at the end of the initialization of `x` (the end of the full-expression).

On the other hand, with `data()&&` returning by value, `x` is bound to a temporary materialization that will have the same life time as `x`. So the dangling reference is avoided.

This return type for `data() &&` is not idiomatic in C++. Usually, accessor functions return a reference and such use-case as the one above will probably raises the "dangling reference alarm" of any code reviewer.

This definition of `data()&&` is smart but it breaks a common convention.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` or `&&` after the method serve a special purpose: they serve as a [ref value qualifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8610728/2492058).

In a sense, all of the things you can put after a function's argument declarations (i.e. after the `)` of the parameters) means "only use this method when `*this` has these qualities".

Most typically usage here is `const` qualifying: only calling an override in a const context:

```
class Widget {
void foo() {
cout << "Calling mutable foo\n";
}

void foo() const {
cout << "Calling const foo\n";
}
};
```

The same thing can be done with `&&` or `&`, to tell the compiler to select those overrides when `*this` has matching qualifiers.

*But why would you want to do this?*

This is useful when you want to differentiate between one of the following:

- Give out a reference to some internal data in the normal lvalue case
- Copy out the data in the case where `*this` is an rvalue reference *and will not outlive the calling code's reference*.

A common example that bites a lot of people is the use in for loops.

Consider the following code (building on your `Widget` example):

```
Widget buildWidget() { return Widget(); }

int main() {
   for (auto i : buildWidget().data()) {
      cout << i << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

In this case, the `&&` override would be called because the `Widget` object return by `buildWidget` does not have a name, and is this an rvalue reference.

In concrete terms, as soon as the call to `data()` is done, the underlying `Widget` object (unnamed here) is going to immediately die (it's lifetime will end). If this `&&` override didn't exist, the lvalue reference into its `data` member would point to a destructed object. *This would be undefined behavior*.

In general, this rvalue ref qualifying thing is not a common thing. It really only needs to be used when you run into a situation like this (often when you want to return a value by copy when `*this` may be destructed after the call).