# What is the difference between getters with const, and with const& qualifiers?

Tags: c++, getter, function-qualifier, ref-qualifier

I have watched a [talk](https://youtu.be/9-_TLTdLGtc?t=1510) (exact timestamp, not explained by him) by Nicolai Josuttis (member of C++ standard committee) and he stated that ever since C++11, getters should be written like so:

```
const std::string& getName() const&
{
     return memberStringVar;
}
```

The question is, what is the difference comparing to this getter?

```
const std::string& getName() const
{
     return memberStringVar;
}
```

Comment: `C{}.getName()` is illegal for the first.

Comment: @PasserBy can you explain why this does not work for an rvalue?

Comment: @PasserBy The first one compiles with clang with your example.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood the ref-qualifier, I have no idea why things are the way they are.

Comment: In the talk, there is a `&&` getter (which is for rvalues). If this getter exists, the other must have ref-qualifier, so your second example cannot work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "rvalue reference for \*this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)

Comment: @Pi you might be right, although it is not as straightfoward.

Comment: Diskussed in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381648/triage-post-states-it-is-a-duplicate-but-is-considered-ok?cb=1 as triage fail. migh catch some up/dv

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the example given in the talk, there are two overloads of `getName()` given.
One with the `&&` and the other with the `const&` qualifiers.

Without the `&` after the `const`, the function `const std::string& getName() const` cannot be overloaded with the overload for rvalues `string Customer::getName() &&`.

You would then have to remove the rvalue overload from the code completely if you want it to work.

Since ref qualified member functions were added only in C++11 (making the getter for rvalues possible), the change from `const std::string& getName() const` to `const std::string& getName() const&` was needed to make both overloads possible.

The C++17 standard draft n4659 states :

> 16.1 Overloadable declarations [[over.load]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.load)
>   ...
>
> 2 Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded:
>   ...
>   [(2.3)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.load#2.3) — Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter-type-list as well as member function template declarations with the same name, the same parameter-type-list, and the same template parameter lists **cannot be overloaded if any of them, but not all, have a ref-qualifier**.

Since there is one overload of `getName()` with a ref-qualifier (`&&`), the other one also should have the ref qualifier. This is why `const&` is required.