# ampersand after a c++ function prototype

Tags: c++, function, prototype

Good day!

May I ask the use of the ampersand(s) after a C++ function prototype as in the following struct get members taken from cppreference.com's std::forward page:

```
struct Arg
{
    int i = 1;
    int  get() && { return i; } // call to this overload is rvalue
    int& get() &  { return i; } // call to this overload is lvalue
};
```

?  I understand the ampersands after the function return type but it's the first time I encounter ampersands after the function prototype.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this . Basically, the signature `int  get() &&` is called when the object in question (that is, `*this`) is an rvalue. Mostly in order to move data.

Comment: Thank you @Aziuth!  I now get this together with the answer above.